# Why is this question closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

I am trying to get an app I've been working hard on ready in the Google Play store, and recently ran into an error similar to the one described here:

[Unable to deactivate APK accidentally uploaded to Prod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006165/unable-to-deactivate-apk-accidentally-uploaded-to-prod)

I just had the same situation happen with my app (complete with the same "check for errors in your form" message) and was hoping someone could shed some light on why this is happening. There's some speculation in the comments, but no official answers.

It doesn't seem like it should be closed - the Play Store's Developer Console is probably the most common tool any Android developer is going to use to get their app out into the market. Is there a better SE site for these kinds of questions?

Comment: We've never really decided if Play Store Dev Console questions are on-topic or not, so... we need this discussion.

Comment: This looks like a question for Google's support system.  There is no SE site for Google Support.

Comment: Why is there a Google-Play tag then, if we can't ask questions about that tool?

Comment: For instance, what makes the question I linked above off-topic, while this one is not? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036045/how-to-decide-the-application-name-before-launching-to-playstore

Comment: You're asking about a question that is a year old.

Comment: The existence of tags in no way imply the appropriateness of questions. There are many, many, pointless tags.

Comment: Only someone from Google could answer this, no?

Comment: I think this is off topic still. Its not very software related. I've voted to close it again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect folks interpreted this as a customer support issue - which is fair, given the author admitted he tried to post it in Google's support forums first.

But I'm not sure it is. Unlike the ever-irritating "why was my app rejected?" questions, this appears to be a straight forward tool-usage question, one that *could* be documented. [Here's a similar question with less cruft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377570/apk-stuck-in-prod-in-google-play).

I've edited and re-opened.

Comment: And one of the most frustrating things about stackexchange is rearing its ugly head (that is, all the inconsistency).  The question is on its way to being closed _again_

Answer (score 2):

Off topic means more than just 'the general thing this question was asking about is not acceptable'.  There are various reasons, including things like the OP didn't provide enough info to answer the question.

In this case, I bet this was a "Too Localized" (since it doesn't display which reason, I suspect it's one of the 'old' reasons).  IE, the closers felt it wasn't something that applied to other people, but was likely an issue with his specific form that wasn't something that could be generalized.  This may not be correct, but it's a guess.  It may also be that the original voters felt it needed more information to answer (such as code fragments).

Comment: For what it's worth, I still occasionally see questions in the reopen queue that were closed using one of the "old" reasons, so that part of your answer doesn't seem to be true.

Comment: It's one of the old reasons. The revamp changed it from "off topic" to "off-topic" (notice what's separating the two words).